# libpython2.7.dll.a in cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

The application I installing under cygwin demands the library `libpythonX.Y.dll.a` (`X` - major version, `Y` - minor version). I found just `libpython2.7.dll` and `libpython2.7a`. How can I obtain `libpython2.7.dll.a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the needed package you can use cygcheck

```
cygcheck -p libpython2.7.dll.a

Found 2 matches for libpython2.7.dll.a
python-devel-2.7.12-1 - python-devel: Python language interpreter (installed binaries and support files)
python-2.7.10-1 - python: Python language interpreter (installed binaries and support files)
```

so you need to install python-devel version 2.7.12-1.
The cygwin package python-devel was created from split of the python package, on last version.